# Can I use Worker class in React Native?

Tags: node.js, html, multithreading, react-native

Can I do something like

```
let worker = new Worker("./module.js", {type: "module"});
```

within the context of **react-native**? Does it run the module in background thread? If so, who is handling the thread marshaling? I am thinking this is not possible in the context of react-native since Worker relies on HTML5. Confirmation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you need a 3rd party library for this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-workers

Once you've got it installed just override `Worker`:

```
import { Worker } from 'react-native-workers';
```